# Change color to attributedTitle in UIRefreshControl

Tags: ios, ios6, nsattributedstring, uirefreshcontrol

I'm looking for a way to change color in `UIRefreshControl`.
The text is shown in an `NSAttributedString`, so I try to use `CoreText.framework`:

```
 NSString *s = @"Hello";
 NSMutableAttributedString *a = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s];
 [a addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:(id)[UIColor redColor].CGColor range:NSRangeFromString(s)];
 refreshControl.attributedTitle = a;
```

The text is shown correctly, but the color is always the default gray.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be using `NSForegroundColorAttributeName`, not `kCTForegroundColorAttributeName`.

---

Also, the range being passed should be `NSMakeRange(0, [s length]);`.

Answer (score 11):

In Swift you can set the color of the *attributedTitle* as follows:

```
self.refreshControl?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 182.0/255.0, blue: 8.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)])
```

Answer (score 8):

Simple version:

```
NSAttributedString *title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refresh…" 
attributes: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor redColor]}];
refreshControl.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:title];
```

Answer (score 5):

The "value" parameter you are passing to the "addAttribute" method is a CGColor, use UIColor instead and it will work! [UIColor redColor]<strike>.CGColor</strike>

```
NSString *s = @"Hello";  
NSMutableAttributedString *a = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s];  
[a addAttribute:kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSRangeFromString(s)]; 
refreshControl.attributedTitle = a;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *s = @"Hello";

NSMutableAttributedString *a = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:s];

NSDictionary *refreshAttributes = @{
  NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blueColor],
};

[a setAttributes:refreshAttributes range:NSMakeRange(0, a.length)];

refreshControl.attributedTitle = a;
```

I found the answer here: http://ioscreator.com/format-text-in-ios6-attributed-strings/

Answer (score 2):

Swift Version 4 (iOS 11)

```
        let myString = "Pull to refresh"
        let myAttribute = [ NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.black ]
        let myAttrString = NSAttributedString(string: myString, attributes: myAttribute)
        refreshControl.attributedTitle = myAttrString
```

Answer (score 1):

use this method,

- (id)initWithString:(NSString *)str attributes:(NSDictionary *)attrs;
- (id)initWithAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)attrStr;

therefore,

```
NSMutableDictionary *attributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[attributes setObject:[UIColor whiteColor] forKey:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName]; //background color :optional
[attributes setObject:[UIColor redColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];  //title text color :optionala
NSAttributedString *title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Refresh!!" attributes:attributes];

_refreshcontrol.attributedTitle = [[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString:title];
```